# Java - Omitir posible error como en PHP con @

Tags: java

Quisiera, hacer un condicional que pueda recibir una palabra como el número **uno** o que se ingrese directamente el número **1**.

Teniendo un condicional como el siguiente:

```
if ($var == "Uno" || @intval($var1) == 1){
    echo "Picked 1";
}
```

En PHP se omite cualquier posibilidad de error en la variable o funcion que **tenga un @** antes de, como en el ejemplo de arriba.

*Volviendo a Java*, si el usuario escribe **1** es válido para la primera condición, **"1" != "Uno"**, entonces el proceso continua, hasta llegar a **parseInt(var) == 1**.

El problema es cuando en vez de **1** escribe **uno**, para la primera condición el código es válido, **"Uno" == "Uno"**, pero para **parseInt("Uno")** no es válido el código y es ahí donde está el error.

Lo que tengo es lo siguiente, pero es **claro** que es incorrecto, ya que el **@** no es válido en Java.

```
String var;
if (var == "Uno" || @parseInt(var) == 1){
    System.out.println("Picked 1");
}
```

Cómo sería entonces el código en Java? Soy totalmente nuevo en el lenguaje.

Comment: No entiendo lo que quieres hacer. En Java no puedes parsear una cadena que contega "Uno" a entero: `parseInt (var)==1` ¿Cómo declaras a  `var` antes del if, String, Integer?

Comment: @A.Cedano **var** es String.

Comment: Y claro, es que ahí está el error, que si escribo "Uno", obviamente dará error al intentar realizar **parseInt** pero, de qué forma puede lograrse que si hay un error usando la función **parseInt** la omita, como en el ejemplo de PHP.

Comment: Ya que si la funcion **parseInt** falla, es claro que se ha escrito "Uno" u otra **palabra** entonces, cómo podría realizarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu pregunta es interesante. No lo he probado, pero creo que si intentas el parseInt sobre el valor "Uno" te dará una **excepción**.

Entonces, se podría evaluar llamando a un método `siEntero` el cual te retornará un entero *verdadero* si hay sólo cifras en la cadena, o `null`si la cadena tiene letras, espacios o símbolos:

**Ejemplo completo evaluando varios casos:**

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/BOSkvn)

```
public class HelloWorld {

     public static void main(String []args){

        String var1 = "1";

        if (var1.equals("Uno") || siEntero (var1) == 1){
            System.out.println("CORRECTO: Picked 1 porque la cadena pudo convertirse a entero");
        }

        String var2 = "1 ";

        if (var2.equals("Uno") || siEntero (var2) == 1){
            System.out.println("Caso 2: Picked 1");
        }


       String var3 = "  1  ";

        if (var3.equals("Uno") || siEntero (var3) == 1){
            System.out.println("Caso 3: Picked 1");
        }

     }


    private static  Integer siEntero(String text) {
        try {
                return Integer.parseInt(text);

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("ERROR: La cadena '"+text+"' no pudo convertirse a entero\n  Log:"+e);
                return 0;
        }
    }

}
```

**Resultado:**

> ```
> CORRECTO: Picked 1 porque la cadena pudo convertirse a entero                                                                                        
> ERROR: La cadena '1 ' no pudo convertirse a entero                                                                                                   
>   Log:java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1 "                                                                                        
> ERROR: La cadena '  1  ' no pudo convertirse a entero                                                                                                
>   Log:java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "  1  "
> ```

Comment: Bueno, pero mi situación es que pueda ingresarse **uno** o **1**, y el if debe devolver **true**.

Comment: Revisa la respuesta editada.

Comment: Interesante respuesta.

Comment: Sin embargo el **if** resulta igualmente en error **java.lang.NullPointerException**

Comment: Bueno, siendo **return 0** no da error.

Comment: Ya ya, es que tenía un `return null` he puesto `return 0`... prueba con eso. He editado la respuesta.

Comment: Sí, ahora no da error. Gracias. Aunque en sí la pregunta no está resuelta, me refiero en encontrar un similar al **@** de **PHP**

Comment: No se si existe algo similar en Java. Si no existe, acabamos de inventarlo :)

Comment: Es bueno tener creatividad :)

Comment: Si al método le llamas @ y usas  en el if `@ (var)` ¡ya lo  tienes! pero no creo que Java te deje llamar @ a nuestro método :)

Comment: Lo sé, debido a que **@** no es listado como válido. Sólo [a-zA-Z] Ja!

Answer (score 1):

Para realizar el casting de String a entero debes invocar a la clase `Integer`
ejemplo:

```
public class Test { 

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      int x =Integer.parseInt("9");
      System.out.println(x);
   }
}
```

solucionando tu caso:

```
String var;
if (var == "Uno" || Integer.parseInt(var) == 1){
    System.out.println("Picked 1");
}
```

nota: tambien se puede parsear a otros tipos primitivos, como ser : double, float, etc...